# 1D Array, multiples of 5. Simple but new to coding

Tags: java, arrays

> Write a program that assigns and stores the first 20 multiples of 5 in the array called Data, no other array can be used in the program. The program should output the elements of the array, according to the following:
>
> 1. write only the commands to assign and store the values in Data
> 2. output the array: 10 numbers/line with the sum of each line
> 3. output the array: in reversed order, 5 numbers/line with the sum for each line
> 4. the odd indexed position values (Data[1], Data[3], Data[5],...), 5 values/line and their sum
> 5. the even indexed position values (Data[3], Data[4], Data[6],...), 5 values/line and their sum

I have part 1. so far:

```
int data[]=new int[21]; int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
        data[i]=5*i;
        sum+= data[i];
        if(i%11==0)
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("sum " + sum);

int a[]=new int[21];
    for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
        a[i]=5*i;
        //System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

I need help with the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! People are typically happy to help debug, but stop short of writing code for you. Try pushing ahead on your own, and coming back with a [mcve] of a specific problem.

Comment: You're close on part 1, but a little off. Your `data` array has 21 elements, but you only need 20. Remember that Java arrays are zero-indexed; that is, the first index is 0, second is 1, third is 2, etc... and the last index is going to be n-1 (where n is the size of your array).

Comment: Help ? What do you mean ? Advice maybe ? Insights ? Or do-my-homework ?

Comment: This feels like an exercise in writing for-loops to me.  Hint: There are other ways to increment your loop counter than `++`, such as `+=5`.

Answer (score 1):

As told in comments, we're not here to code for you, [you will lose really important experience about learning how to program](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1).

But I can give you some tips that may help in your assignment.

> 1. write only the commands to assign and store the values in Data
> 2. output the array: 10 numbers/line with the sum of each line

**DONE, RIGHT? ;)**

> 3. output the array: in reversed order, 5 numbers/line with the sum for each line

We wont speak now in built in functions of `Arrays` or `Collections`.
 **Do it easy:** to reverse array reverse the loop:

```
for(int i=20i>=0;i--){
```

Better use the array length:

```
for(int i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--){
```

---

To make increments (for example by 5) you can use `d[i] += 5` equivalent to `d[i] = d[i] + 5` in the same way `a++` is `a = a + 1`.

you need 5 values per line right? To know when to finish a line, use [modulus or remainder operator `%`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

```
if (i % 5 == 0)
```

*That means, if modulus of i / 5 equals 0 (so 5 multiple), use it to print sum and new line (`println`)*

> 4. the odd indexed position values (Data[1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1), Data[3], Data[5],...), 5 values/line and their sum

**Remembering for this part**: `i+=2` is same than `i = i + 2` ;)

> 5. the even indexed position values (Data[3], Data[4], Data[6],...), 5 values/line and their sum

To sum, create a new variable to store values **OUTSIDE** the loop, and sum inside:

```
int total = 0;
for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
    total += data[i]; // equals to total = total + data[i]
    // more code
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
         // print total of the line and skip line
         // reset total variable total = 0;
    }
    // more code
 }
```